# how to cancel refresh set by meta tag in html

Tags: html

I have used `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=https://www.test.com />` but i have to cancel it if 
`<a href="https://www.test1.com"><button>Finsh</button></a>` finish button is clicked.But this code refreshes in every 10 sec i am using the tool where javascript is also not supported.Can i cancel the time which i setted using meta tag..??

Comment: Am using a tool where javascript is also not supported

Comment: Why is JavaScript not supported? What tool are you using? If you can not use scripts, there is most probably no way to achieve what you are trying to do... sorry about that :(.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to refresh the page every ten seconds in the first place.

```
<script>
    timerID = setInterval(function() {location.reload();},10000);
</script>
<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="clearInterval(timerID);">
        Stop refreshing
    </button>
</body>
```

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vk48shgf/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Please click the tick next to the answer to accept it :).